# .ttf file does not work

Tags: php, css, captcha

I've a `.ttf` file to be loaded to a captcha image. But my `.ttf` just doesn't work. When I include a`.ttf` file, the image does not load and gives an error.

Here's my captcha code:

```
<?php

session_start();

$md5_hash = md5(rand(0,999));

$captcha = substr($md5_hash, 16, 5);

$_SESSION["captcha"] = $captcha;

$width = 205;
$height = 60;

$image = imagecreate($width, $height);

$white = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
$black = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($image, 204, 204, 204);

imagefill($image, 0, 0, $white);

$font = imageloadfont('Xeron.ttf');
imagestring($image, $font, 70, 20, $captcha, $black);

imagerectangle($image, 0, 0, $width-1, $height-1, $grey);
imageline($image, 0, $height/2, $width, $height/2, $grey);
imageline($image, $width/2, 0, $width/2, $height, $grey);

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");

imagejpeg($image);

imagedestroy($image);

?>
```

I'm new to php, Help please..

**Edit**

I've even tried it with the following code and still my image doesn't load

```
$captcha_num = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
$captcha_num = substr(str_shuffle($captcha_num), 0, 6);
$_SESSION["code"] = $captcha_num;

$font_size = 30;
$img_width = 70;
$img_height = 40;

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

$image = imagecreate($img_width, $img_height); // create background image with dimensions
imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255); // set background color

$text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0); // set captcha text color

imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, 15, 30, $text_color, 'Xeron.ttf', $captcha_num);
imagejpeg($image);
```

Comment: what is location of font xeron.ttf ??

Comment: it is in the same location as my captcha.php

Comment: ok.. do u tried with another .ttf font ??

Comment: Try changing 'Xeron.ttf' to './Xeron.ttf' to clarify that you want the current working directory. Or specify the full path. What does your error log show? FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: @DrMJ yes i've tried with a different .ttf file. But still it doesn't load.

Comment: How do i modify php.ini file @WillBickford

Comment: @Lublaut - if you take a closer look at the doc page for imageloadfont, you'll see the following text `imageloadfont() loads a user-defined *bitmap* and returns its identifier.` Reading further, you may reach the end of the man page and see the comment that says: `"Remember - GD fonts aren't antialiased.  If you're planning on using a pre-existing (TrueType) font, you may want to consider using imagettftext() instead of phillip's function."` ;) Docs. Always read the docs....

Comment: Question edited!!

Answer (score 0):

I am providing a sample code for php captcha... you can try it with your values, fonts, font colors etc..

**captcha.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();
//Settings: You can customize the captcha here
$image_width = 210;
$image_height = 60;
$characters_on_image = 7;
$font = './monofont.ttf';

//The characters that can be used in the CAPTCHA code.
//avoid confusing characters (l 1 and i for example)
$possible_letters = '23456789ABDEFGHLMNQRTWY';
$random_dots = 15;
$random_lines = 3;
$captcha_text_color="#4593BC";
$captcha_noice_color = "#34495e";

$code = '';

$i = 0;
 while ($i < $characters_on_image) { 
 $code .= substr($possible_letters, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible_letters)-1), 1);
 $i++;
}


$font_size = $image_height * 0.6;
$image = @imagecreate($image_width, $image_height);


/* setting the background, text and noise colours here */
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);

$arr_text_color = hexrgb($captcha_text_color);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, $arr_text_color['red'], 
    $arr_text_color['green'], $arr_text_color['blue']);

$arr_noice_color = hexrgb($captcha_noice_color);
$image_noise_color = imagecolorallocate($image, $arr_noice_color['red'], 
    $arr_noice_color['green'], $arr_noice_color['blue']);


/* generating the dots randomly in background */
for( $i=0; $i<$random_dots; $i++ ) {
imagefilledellipse($image, mt_rand(0,$image_width),
 mt_rand(0,$image_height), 2, 3, $image_noise_color);
}


/* generating lines randomly in background of image */
for( $i=0; $i<$random_lines; $i++ ) {
imageline($image, mt_rand(0,$image_width), mt_rand(0,$image_height),
mt_rand(0,$image_width), mt_rand(0,$image_height), $image_noise_color);
}


/* create a text box and add 6 letters code in it */
$textbox = imagettfbbox($font_size, 0, $font, $code); 
$x = ($image_width - $textbox[4])/2;
$y = ($image_height - $textbox[5])/2;
imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, $x, $y, $text_color, $font , $code);


/* Show captcha image in the page html page */
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');// defining the image type to be shown in browser window
imagejpeg($image);//showing the image
imagedestroy($image);//destroying the image instance
 $_SESSION['captcha'] = $code;

function hexrgb ($hexstr){
  $int = hexdec($hexstr);
  return array("red" => 0xFF & ($int >> 0x10),
           "green" => 0xFF & ($int >> 0x8),
           "blue" => 0xFF & $int);
}
?>
```

**index.php**

```
 //to display captcha image

<img src="captcha.php?rand=<?php echo rand();?>" id='captchaimg' >
```

Comment: I have edited some part... create captcha.php file and keep it in root folder and then add code given for index.php

Comment: please poke me on my whatsapp no 9881150272